# java script functions for different textbox my code here

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code in html and java script. I coded same things thrice, I want to do it once... what to do...............

```
<input type="text" name="option1" id="option1" onblur="calc_amt(1);">
<input type="text" name="price1" id="price1"  onblur="calc_amt(1);">
<input type="text" name="amount1" id="amount1" readonly>

<input type="text" name="option2" id="option2" onblur="calc_amt(2);">
<input type="text" name="price2" id="price2"  onblur="calc_amt(2);">
<input type="text" name="amount2" id="amount2" readonly>

<input type="text" name="option3" id="option3" onblur="calc_amt(3);">
<input type="text" name="price3" id="price3"  onblur="calc_amt(3);">
<input type="text" name="amount3" id="amount3" readonly>


<script>
function calc_amt(val){                             
                if(val==1){                                     
                    var option1 = document.getElementById("option1").value;
                    var pri1 = document.getElementById("price1").value;
                    ....
                    document.getElementById("amount1").value=amoun1 ;
                }
                if(val==2){                                     
                    var option2 = document.getElementById("option2").value;
                    var pri2 = document.getElementById("price2").value;
                    ...
                    document.getElementById("amount2").value=amoun2;
                }
                if(val==3){                                     
                    var option3 = document.getElementById("option3").value;
                    var pri3 = document.getElementById("price3").value;
                    ....
                    document.getElementById("amount3").value=amoun3;
                }
                var amoun1=document.getElementById("amount1").value;
                var amoun2=document.getElementById("amount2").value;
                var amoun3=document.getElementById("amount3").value;
                var tot = Number(amt1)+Number(amt2)+Number(amt3);
                document.getElementById("amount").value=tot;
            }
</script>
```

how do solve it by coding only once... I am beginner please help me.... any other ideas to solve this.. i need a solution like inheritance.

Comment: what is amoun1,amoun2 amoun3 ?

Comment: price1*option1=amoun1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can further reduce above script like this. Your `amoun` is unclear for though. However you can reduce the code like this. This is just an idea and make sure you match the variables with correct statement.

```
<script>
function calc_amt(val){                             

                var option1 = document.getElementById("option"+val).value;
                var pri1 = document.getElementById("price"+val).value;
                ....
                document.getElementById("amount"+val).value=""+amount+val ;

                var amoun1=document.getElementById("amount1").value;
                var amoun2=document.getElementById("amount2").value;
                var amoun3=document.getElementById("amount3").value;
                var tot = Number(amt1)+Number(amt2)+Number(amt3);
                document.getElementById("amount").value=tot;
            }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
if(val==1){                                     
  var option1 = document.getElementById("option1").value;
  var pri1 = document.getElementById("price1").value;
  document.getElementById("amount1").value=amoun1 ;
}
```

with:

```
 var amoun = document.getElementById("amount" + val).value;
 var option = document.getElementById("option" + val).value;
 var pri = document.getElementById("price" + val).value;
 document.getElementById("amount" + val).value=amoun;
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY...
Remove all inline handler and use blur handler  like in demo

```
$("input[type=text]").on("blur", function () {

    var id = this.id;
    var last = id.charAt(id.length - 1);           // get last id string value
    var optionValue = $("#option" + last).val();
    var priceValue = $("#price" + last).val();
    var option = isNaN(optionValue) ? 0 : +optionValue;   // check is nan 
    var price = isNaN(priceValue) ? 0 : +priceValue;

    $("#amount" + last).val(option * price);  // display multiply value

    $("#amount").text($("input[type=text][id^=amount]").map(function () {  // collect all amount1,2,3  values 
        var value = $(this).val();
        return isNaN(value) ? 0 : +value;
    }).get().reduce(function (a, b) {              // add total value
        return a + b;
    }));
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z9wkLsa0/1/)

OPTIMIZED CODE

```
$("input[type=text]:not([readonly])").on("blur", function () {

    var obj = $();

    obj = obj.add($(this)).add($(this).prevUntil('[readonly]')).add($(this).nextUntil('[readonly]'));

    $(this).nextAll('[readonly]').first().val($.map(obj, function (val, i) {
        return parseInt(val.value, 10) || 0;
    }).reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a * b
    }, 1));

    $("#amount").text($("input[type=text][id^=amount]").map(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        return isNaN(value) ? 0 : +value;
    }).get().reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }));


});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z9wkLsa0/5/)